# How to style Bibliography codes

Tags: linux, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

Consider inline bibliography in a document, created by *Insert > Bibliography Entry > New*. This way, I can insert a short code for each bibliography at a place in the document as i chose. See image.

[image]

(Please forgive the typos)

See, the codes are styled with a gray background, and black font.

If I export to PDF, then it has no style at all.

[image]

I would like to know, if there is a simple way in a few clicks, to style these inline codes, so that they will appear in the PDF file as italicized, and of a different color.

As an attempt of solution, I tried to change the bibliography style, but that only impacts the final bibliography inserted at the very end, not the inline codes.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there's (AFAIK) no simple way. It would be simple if LO would assign a specific character style to each citation, but it doesn't.

Thus, as far as I see, you have two options:

- assign a custom character style to each citation manually;
- use a macro for this task (see below).

For me, the following code worked:

```vb
Sub AddBiblioStyle

   Dim oDoc,oFields,oEnum,ThisField
   oDoc = ThisComponent
   oFields = oDoc.getTextFields
   oEnum = oFields.createEnumeration
   While oEnum.HasMoreElements
       ThisField = oEnum.nextElement
       ThisField.Anchor.CharStyleName = "Biblio"
   Wend

End Sub
```

<sup>Based on https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/find-field-replace-by-plain-text-keep-formating/62591/3</sup>

This simply applies a **[character style](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.2/en-US/text/swriter/01/05130002.html)** named "Biblio" to all text fields in the current document. That character style must exist at runtime, otherwise you'll receive an error. It will affect all text fields, thus i can't predict any side effects.

To use the macro:

1. Create a custom character style with the desired features (text color, background, font and so on);
2. Add the macro to your document (Menu Extras -> Macros -> Manage -> Basic);
3. Replace "Biblio" in the macro code with the name of your custom character style;
4. Execute the macro.